# Submit POST data when Javascript opens a new page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, post

In the Wordpress build my company has, we have some data that needs to be passed along when a page is previewed. Because it can be lengthy, my boss wants me to stop the native functionality when the preview button is clicked and instead open a new tab, submitting the data we need to pass via POST.

I seem to be having trouble finding out how to do this, or if its possible. AJAX won't help since I need to pass the data along to the new page, but otherwise, I don't see what can be done.

The only option I've been able to come up with is to dynamically create a hidden form on the post edit page that I can populate and submit via Javascript when the preview button is clicked, but the concern is that seems hacky. Additionally, I'm not sure if you can submit a form to a new tab?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can POST a `<form>` to a separate window/tab - that's what the "target" attribute is for.

Comment: Cool, wasn't sure if target would work on a form.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use a hidden form that makes a post request when the preview button is clicked? like so:
`<form action="#" method="post" target="_blank">`
  `<input type="hidden" id="myhiddenfield" data=""/>`
  `<input type="submit" id="preview" name="preview" value="preview" />`
`</form>`

I know this is what you wrote in your question, however I cannot see how this is less hacky than listening for a button, generating a request, and opening up a window to the output of that request.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I think I'm just a bit curious IF it can be done via JS, or if the hidden form is the way I have to go.

Comment: You could make an ajax call, and return in the ajax reply the relevant information, i.e. the url arguments id=blahblah, and then have JS open a new window/tab to the relevant page viewer.php?id=blahblah, however this is very hacky and much worse practice than the preview form "hack"

Comment: Yah, the problem is the data being sent could easily be larger then GET allows, thus why I was looking for a method using POST. I have to do a AJAX request to get the extra data anyway, so the first part is already done.

Comment: You can use both ajax and the form using post. I don't understand how a GET request is relevant.

Comment: I meant opening a new page with POST data; not the form or the AJAX.

Comment: You can open a new page using a form, in a new tab/window, using the code posted above.  

With respect to the ajax solution.

Button press -> AJAX POST(args) -- returns id=blahblah --> window.open(url+id=blahblah, "_blank") --> done